# Calculating a difference in numbers

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to calculate a difference in numbers with Excel 2010. Let's say I have four cells (110, 108, 106 and 104). It's pretty clear that the difference between the four numbers in total (so starting and ending one) is 6. This is the answer I want in the fifth cell; 6. However, if I add another cell between cell 4 and 5 (4 being the lowest number and 5 being the difference), I want the newly created 6 cell (the old 5 - difference answer) to also include the new fifth cell, which is - for example - 100, making the difference 10.

Answer (score 2):

`=MAX(A1:A4)-MIN(A1:A4)`

will return the answer you're looking for, and the ranges will dynamically update if you insert cells into the `A1:A4` range.